# Understanding session with fastApi dependency

Tags: python, django, fastapi

I am new to Python and was studying FastApi and SQL model.

Reference link: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/session-with-dependency/#the-with-block

Here, they have something like this

```
def create_hero(*, session: Session = Depends(get_session), hero: HeroCreate):
    db_hero = Hero.from_orm(hero)
    session.add(db_hero)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(db_hero)
    return db_hero
```

Here I am unable to understand this part

```
    session.add(db_hero)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(db_hero)
```

What is it doing and how is it working?

Couldn't understand this

```
In fact, you could think that all that block of code inside of the create_hero() function is still inside a with block for the session, because this is more or less what's happening behind the scenes.

But now, the with block is not explicitly in the function, but in the dependency above:
```

Comment: they made a context manager and using that object you are setting up the session, don't know what Depends does there , but pretty much this is it

Comment: `session` here refers to the database session - i.e. a session where different ORM objects are tracked and referenced from start to finish. `add` adds that ORM object to the session (i.e. that you want it tracked in the database), while `commit` actually writes the changes to the database. Calling `refresh` reads the object back from the database, populating it with fields that are generated server side (such as the `id` field usually).

Answer (score 0):

It's an explanation from [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#what-does-the-session-do) what is a session

> In the most general sense, the Session establishes all conversations
> with the database and represents a “holding zone” for all the objects
> which you’ve loaded or associated with it during its lifespan. It
> provides the interface where SELECT and other queries are made that
> will return and modify ORM-mapped objects. The ORM objects themselves
> are maintained inside the Session, inside a structure called the
> identity map - a data structure that maintains unique copies of each
> object, where “unique” means “only one object with a particular
> primary key”.

So

```py
# This line just simply create a python object
# that sqlalchemy would "understand".
db_hero = Hero.from_orm(hero)

# This line add the object `db_hero` to a “holding zone”
session.add(db_hero)

# This line take all objects from a “holding zone” and put them in a database
# In our case we have only one object in this zone, 
# but it is possible to have several
session.commit()

# This line gets created row from the database and put it to the object. 
# It means it could have new attributes. For example id, 
# that database would set for this new row
session.refresh(db_hero)
```